# Call category or test name from code in MSTest during test run

Tags: c#, c, testing, mstest

Is there any way to call category or test name from code in MSTest during test run?

Comment: It's more preferable to use categories and not overload test names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't now if it's possible for the test category but you can call the test name using the [`TestContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx).

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("TestMethod1", TestContext.TestName, "Something went really wrong...");
    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
}
```